# Detailed list view - top alignment question

Tags: swiftui

Added on the 24th of July:

This line of code fixes the space in the detail view. However... in the list view the title has become a lot smaller too.

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Egg management"), displayMode: .inline)
```

Added on the 23th of July:

Thanks to the tips I made a lot of progress. Especially the tip to add borders does wonders. You see exactly what happens!

However, there seems to be a difference between the Xcode Preview canvas, the simulator and the physical device. Is this a bug because -after all- it is still beta? Or is there anything I can do?

As you can see in the images... only in the Xcode Preview canvas the view connects to the top of the screen.

I believe it has something to do with the tabbar. Since when I look at the Xcode Preview canvas with the tabbar... that space above is also there. Any idea how to get rid of that?

[image: Xcode Preview canvas]
[image: Simulator]
[image: Screenshot iPhone 7+]

---

Original postings:

This is my code for a detailed list view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentDetail : View {

    @State var photo = true

    var text = "Een kip ..."
    var imageList = "Dag-3"
    var day = "3.circle"
    var date = "9 augustus 2019"
    var imageDetail = "Day-3"
    var weight = "35.48"

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {

            Text(date)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)

            ZStack (alignment: .topLeading){

                Image(photo ? imageDetail : imageList)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .padding(.trailing, 0)
                    .tapAction {
                        self.photo.toggle() }

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: day)
                        .resizable()
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                    Spacer()

                    Image(systemName: photo ?  "photo" : "pencil.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }

            Text(text)
                .lineLimit(6)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.leading, 6)

        } .padding(20)

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentDetail_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentDetail()
    }
}
#endif
```

Also included is the preview canvas. What I don't get is how I can make sure the text and photo are aligned to the top (instead of the middle). I tried with Spacers, padding etc.

I must be overseeing something small I guess... but. Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Added:
After both answers I added a Spacer() after the last text. In Xcode in the preview canvas everything looks okay now. But on my connected iPhone 7 Plus there are some problems: the view is not aligned to the top, and the image is cropped (icon on the right is gone; white banding to the right).

Comment: Sorry, I was not subscribed to your question, so I only got notifications when you commented on my answer. I am just seeing your updates now. I see that you made a LOT of progress. Concerning Previews, I gave up on them by the second day I started with SwiftUI and never looked back. I'm not planning on using them until at least the GM. At their current state I don't trust them and I consider them a waste of time. Having to double check everything! Also, when you get different results, probably 99% of the time, it is the preview that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Great article on your site btw (SwiftUI’s Layout Magic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a Spacer() after the last text shifts everything to the top. Tested on iPhone Xr simulator (not preview).

[image]

```swift
   ...

   Text(text)
       .lineLimit(6)
       .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
       .padding(.leading, 6)

   Spacer()
}
```

To remove the space at the top:

```swift
    VStack {
        ...
    }
    .padding(20)
    .navigationBarTitle("TITLE", displayMode: .inline)
```

Comment: To troubleshoot further, please let us know the exact size of your image, so we can reproduce the problem . I mean the actual pixels of the image on file (not how it is shown). Also note that one of the best tools for understanding (and then troubleshooting) layout problem, is adding borders everywhere. This way you see exactly how much space each container is taking. The results may surprise you. Start by adding borders to your VStack and ZStack. Note that if a border doesn't show up, it may be because it is being laying right behind another border.

Comment: Also, the space to the right of the image can be removed if you change your aspectRatio from .fit to .fill.

Comment: And finally, judging by your screenshot, the white space at the top seems to be introduced by the fact you are inside of a NavigationView. You get rid of it, you may make the navigation bar title .inline. I'll update my posted answer.

Comment: Okay. Since I want to learn as much out of it as I can... I'm diving in a bit first. I've also added some extra content to that view / screen, so I have to finish that first (otherwise it is a moving target). Thanks for the advices!

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of what a `Spacer()` does. It "moves" the views as far apart as it can - at least, without a specific space.

So you have this:

```
VStack {
    Text
    ZStack {
        Image
        HStack {
            Image
            Spacer()
            Image
        }
    }
    Text
}
```

All told, going from *inner* to *outer*, you have a horizontal stack of two images placed as far apart (the spacer is between them) inside of a "Z axis" stack that places an image on top of them, inside of a vertical stack that has some text above it.

So if you want to move everything in that vertical stack to the top, you simply need to add one last spacer:

```
VStack {
    Text
    ZStack {
        Image
        HStack {
            Image
            Spacer()
            Image
        }
    }
    Text
    Spacer() // <-- ADD THIS
}
```

Last note: Don't be afraid to adding additional "stacks" to your view. In terms of memory footprint, it's really just a *single* view with no performance hit.

**EDIT:** I took your *original* view and changed everything to placeholders...

```
var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
        Text("Text #1")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
        ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text( "Image #1")
            HStack {
                Text("Image #2")
                Spacer()
                Text("Image #3")
            }
        }
        Text("Text #2")
            .lineLimit(6)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.leading, 6)
    } .padding(20)
}
```

As expected, everything is vertically centered. Adding a `Spacer()` below "Text #2" throws everything to the top. A couple of thoughts:

- Starting there, and add in your `Image` views one by one. Add in the modifiers like that also.
- I don't have the specific images you are rendering, so maybe put a noticeable background color on various things (orange is my personal favorite) and see if the top `Image` **is** actually on top but the image makes it appear as though it isn't. A border would work pretty well too.

Comment: Thanks. When I add that Spacer in the Preview Canvas everything looks fine, just like the screen Kontiki posted. On my connected iPhone 7 Plus however, there is still a lot of room between the top and the first text. Also... on my iPhone 7 Plus the image is a lot smaller. I'll add a screen dump to my original post.

Comment: @arakweker, it sounds like you understand better what a `Spacer` does. That's the first thing needed. It seems like you have *a few* other issues related to modifiers of `Views` placed *within* your stacks. Probably related to padding, dividers, etc. (And for `Image`, don't forget, it's more a `UIImageView` than `UIImage` and, yes, I see you know about `resizable`.) I'm glad I helped. And yes, those details (along with @kontiki) should get you the rest of the way there. Please, post an update. We'll edit our answers accordingly.